# apache rewrite .htaccess google adwords gclid

Tags: apache, htaccess, lamp, url-rewriting, google

I've got an url coming in as:

```
/index.php?/location/&gclid=287ejek22kj
```

This is going to a 404 page because of the gclid...

I need it to go to:

```
/index.php?/location
```

I've tried this, with no success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)&gclid=(.*)$  $1 [L]
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason you're leaving in the /index.php? I assume that's your controller script, but using rewrites, you could easily make it simply make it `/location`. The main issue with what you're trying to do is that you're trying to capture the QUERY_STRING (everything after the ?). You need to treat this specially in RewriteRules

Comment: in the next set of rules i'm removing the index.php... but i'm having the issue with simply ignoring the gclid... on those adword pages only of course

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much answered in concept at least here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111182/rewriting-url-with-selected-query-string-parameters-in-htaccess

Comment: thanks, but i need to see it with my conditions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're ending up with AdWords auto tagging appended to a URL without the proper structure but if you don't want the `gclid` parameter at all you could alway just switch off autotagging in AdWords. You shouldn't need to remove it using a rewrite rule as it's just an option that you can choose not to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Catch any Google campaigns directed to the home page
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(gclid=.*)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/ [L,PT]

  # Everything else 

</IfModule>
```